# How to place a jQuery snippet into a global file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript file here http://www.problemio.com/js/problemio.js and I am trying to place some jQuery code into it that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    queue = new Object; 
    queue.login = false; 

     var $dialog = $('#loginpopup')
       .dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         title: 'Login Dialog'
       }); 

       var $problemId = $('#theProblemId', '#loginpopup');

        $("#newprofile").click(function () 
        {
          $("#login_div").hide();
          $("#newprofileform").show();
        });

    // Called right away after someone clicks on the vote up link
    $('.vote_up').click(function() 
    {        
        var problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");
        queue.voteUp = $(this).attr('problem_id');

        voteUp(problem_id);

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;       
    });

    var voteUp = function(problem_id) 
    {
        alert ("In vote up function, problem_id: " + problem_id );
        queue.voteUp = problem_id;

        var dataString = 'problem_id=' + problem_id + '&vote=+';

        if ( queue.login = false) 
        {
            // Call the ajax to try to log in...or the dialog box to log in. requireLogin()
        } 
        else 
        {
            // The person is actually logged in so lets have him vote
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {           
                    alert ("vote success, data: " + data);

                    // Try to update the vote count on the page
                    //$('p').each(function() 
                    //{ 
                        //on each paragraph in the page:
                      //  $(this).find('span').each() 
                      //  { 
                            //find each span within the paragraph being iterated over

                       // }
                     //}                      

                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    alert ("vote error");
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;

                    if ( errorMessage == "not_logged_in" )
                    {
                        //set the current problem id to the one within the dialog
                        $problemId.val(problem_id);                 

                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        $dialog.dialog('open');

                        alert ("after dialog was open");

                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ("not");
                    }    
                } // End of error  case 
        }





            }); // Closing AJAX call.
    };

    $('.vote_down').click(function() 
    {
        alert("down");

        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=-';        

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });    

    $('#loginButton', '#loginpopup').click(function() 
    {
    alert("in login button fnction");
            $.ajax({
                url:'url to do the login',
                success:function() {
                    //now call cote up 
                    voteUp($problemId.val());
                }
            });
        });    
});
</script>
```

There are two reasons why I am trying to do that:

1) I am guessing this is just good practice (hopefully it will be easier to keep track of my global variables, etc.
2) More importantly, I am trying to call the voteUp(someId) function in the original code from the problemio.js file, and I am getting an error that it is an undefined function, so I figured I'd have better luck calling that function if it was in a global scope.  Am I correct in my approach?

So can I just copy/paste the code I placed into this question into the problemio.js file, or do I have to remove certain parts of it like the opening/closing tags?  What about the document.ready() function? Should I just have one of those in the global file? Or should I have multiple of them and that won't hurt?

Thanks!!

Comment: `if ( queue.login = false) ` is incorrect, you need two `==` for comparison. Besides that, use `{}` instead of `new Object()` and pass an object instead of a string to the ajax `data`. Last but not least, note that there is `.data(name[, value])` which you can use instead of `.attr('data-name')`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster ah good point.  Fixed the == in my code.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I am a bit of a JS newb, what is the difference between using the {} syntax and the new Object()  ? How exactly should I change it?

Comment: Mainly it looks nicer. `var queue = {};` or even `var queue = { login: false };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I am guessing this is just good practice (hopefully it will be
>   easier to keep track of my global variables, etc.

Yes and no, you now have your 'global' variables in one spot but the chances that you're going to collide with 'Global' variables (ie those defined by the browser) have increased 100% :)

For example say you decided to have a variable called `location`, as soon as you give that variable a value the browser decides to fly off to another URL because `location` is a reserved word for redirecting.

The solution to this is to use namespacing, as described [here](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing)

> 2) More importantly, I am trying to call the voteUp(someId) function
>   in the original code from the problemio.js file, and I am getting an
>   error that it is an undefined function, so I figured I'd have better
>   luck calling that function if it was in a global scope. Am I correct
>   in my approach?

Here's an example using namespacing that will call the `voteUp` function:

```
(function($) {

    var myApp = {};

    $('.vote_up').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myApp.voteUp();
    });

    myApp.voteUp = function() {
        console.log("vote!");
    }

})(jQuery);
```

> What about the document.ready() function? Should I just have one of
>   those in the global file? Or should I have multiple of them and that
>   won't hurt?

You can have as many document.ready listeners as you need, you are not overriding document.ready you are listening for that event to fire and then defining what will happen. You could even have them in separate javascript files.

Comment: thank you - I refactored the code to be in one file, but I still get the undefined function error.  Would you mind taking a look at the updated code I am about to change the original answer with?

Comment: actually, to make it simple, here is how I am defining the function:     var voteUp = function(problem_id) {  ...and that is above the call to it which is undefined.  Is this just wrong syntax? You have it slightly different in your suggestion.  Now sure what the implications between the differences is.

Comment: You don't have to use `var` to declare a function, you can also write `function voteUp(){}` or if you really want to make it global `window.voteUp = function(){}`. If it's still undefined when using the window.voteUp method then something else is going on (load issues).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your page is finding the jquery file BEFORE this file is included in the page. If jquery is not there first you will get function not defined. Otherwise, you might have other things conflicting with your jquery, I would look into jquery noConflict.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

as seen here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Happy haxin

_wryteowl

Comment: there is already jQuery in that problemio.js code.  So the undefined isn't from that.  My guess is that the problemio.js code is unaware of the voteUp() in the page where everything originates, but I am not sure how to increase the scope of the voteUp() function.

Comment: -1, noConflict prevents jQuery from breaking *other* things that might collide with it. so if his jQuery code is not working this call won't fix it (but rather break it until he wraps his code in a function making `$` available again)

Answer (score 0):

Extending what KreeK has already provided: there's no need to define your "myApp" within the document ready function. Without testing, I don't know off the top of my head if doing so is a potential source for scope issues. However, I CAN say that the pattern below will not have scope problems. If this doesn't work, the undefined is possibly a script-loading issue (loading in the right order, for example) rather than scope.

```
var myApp = myApp || {}; // just adds extra insurance, making sure "myApp" isn't taken

myApp.voteUp = function() {
  console.log("vote!");
}

$(function() { // or whatever syntax you prefer for document ready
  $('.vote_up').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myApp.voteUp();
  });
});
```